# VBA / Pivot Table / Comparing values from two fields and highlighting

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

Hoping you can help.

From the example Pivot (below), I need to highlight any [Country] that does not equal GB and has a [Confirmed] status of YES (bearing in mind we deal with many different countries so hardcoding each country is not an option)
[image "a"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dvd2.png)

I've tried using many different codes and although I am able to highlight specific values for one PivotField, I am unable to work out how to compare different fields within a Pivot.

Here are a couple of snippets of what I have been working with which has changed a multitude of times:-

```
If Worksheets("Sheet1").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Confirmed").PivotItems("YES") = "YES" _
And Worksheets("Sheet1").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Country").PivotItems("GB") <> "GB" Then
Worksheets("Sheet1").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Country").PivotItems("GB").LabelRange.Interior.Color = vbYellow
End If
```

---

```
Dim PvtTbl As PivotTable
Dim PvtFld As PivotField
Dim PvtFld2 As PivotField

Set PvtTbl = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1")

Set PvtFld = PvtTbl.PivotFields("Confirmed")
Set PvtFld2 = PvtTbl.PivotFields("Country")

For Each PvtItm In PvtFld.PivotItems
    If PvtItm.Name = "YES" Then
        For Each PvtItm2 In PvtFld2.PivotItems
            If PvtItm2.Name = "GB" Then
            PvtItm2.LabelRange.Interior.Color = vbRed
            End If
        Next PvtItm2
    End If
Next PvtItm
```

I've got close, but not quite:-
[image "b"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qA7R.png)

Thanks in advance for your help. :)

Comment: How can it be that your example shows Red and your code is going with vbBlue?

Comment: Thanks for the spot. Have changed.